# Procreate brush overlap

Tags: brush, procreate

I have tried everything to change the brush in Procreate so that when I color on the same stroke the texture won't overlap but nothing works. What should I do?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "color on the same stroke"? Like drawing an ampersand or a figure 8 where you cross the stroke?

Comment: "Everything" is a big word, what have you tried so far? Can you provide a visual exampe of what you want to achieve? If not by Procreate, maybe handcraft and example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

A generic workaround, valid in all multilayer painting programs:

Avoid the whole problem by drawing to a new layer. When the new layer is below the 1st layer in the layer stack, your new stroke is below the things in the 1st layer. You can move items in the layer stack as you like, except in some programs the background stays in the bottom.

The new stroke can be seen through the older strokes if they are not fully opaque or you have defined some blending to happen between the layers.

Another general trick is to use selections. You may select the already painted area and then invert the selection. Then your paintbrush doesn't obscure what's painted before making the selection.

**A hint:** To get something exact you should give some images which specify the actual painting problem.

Comment: Why do you keep making new accounts? Why not just stick to one account and build a reputation? I don't get it.